# Attach multiple photos under one question in Survey123 Connect

Tags: arcgis

Is it possible to attach more than one photo to a note field in Survey123 Connect? I am not sure how to specify more than one file to attach. The easy solution would be to have a different field per photo, but I was curious to see if there is a way to include more than one photo per field. And to be clear, I am trying to add attachments to a survey that can be viewed while using the survey, not take a picture.

| Type | Name | label | appearance | media::image |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| note | drone_registration | Drone Registration | multiline | UAS_Cert_FATMPRK.png, UAS_Cert_FATMPRK2.png |